# Questions related to getting started with specific programming tasks

Tags: discussion

What is the recommended ways to help a user who wants to use a technology, but are so new to it that they are unable to even provide a code example, nor are sure where to start?  I'm pretty sure [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504226/column-hide-show-and-making-changes-to-database) are off topic for Stack Overflow, but are they on topic for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Definitely not an appropriate question for Programmers.SE.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Where to Start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start)